# angular form submission with dynamic ng-modal data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

initially i am new to angular.i am submitting a simple form-submit, with lot of input fields with will come from the an object.my issue is i am not able to collect the modified form data json on button ng-click.

```
<form id="fmsubmit" role="form">
   <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in showCase.person">
     <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
     <input type="text" ng-disabled="key=='rowId'" class="form-control"  id="{{key}}" placeholder="{{key}}" name="{{key}}" value={{value}} ng-modal="row[value]"/>
   </div>
 <button type="submit" ng-click="showCase.submitData(row)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my controller

```
$scope.submitData = function(person){
  console.log(person);
}
```

Comment: its typo `ng-model` instead of `ng-modal`

Comment: thanks.. i changed "ng-model" then also it is not working.

Comment: Where is row defined? Maybe try `ng-repeat="row in showCase.person"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: Typo in ng-model, row is undefined. 
To be honest I'm not completly sure what you want to do. I assume that you want to generate forms based on object structure and after changes in forms get updated object. If you want descrbied scenario by me then you have here fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alepkowski/fjjmeset/2/)

```
<form id="fmsubmit" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in showCase.person">
            <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{key}}" ng-disabled="key=='rowId'" placeholder="{{key}}" name="{{key}}" ng-model="showCase.person[key]" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="showCase.submitData(showCase.person)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
$scope.showCase = {};
$scope.showCase.person = {
    "id": 2,
        "project": "wewe2012",
        "date": "2013-02-26",
        "description": "ewew",
        "eet_no": "ewew",
};
$scope.showCase.submitData = function (person) {
    console.log(person);
    alert(JSON.stringify(person));
};
}
```

Edit: 
If you want to have a new variable "row" responsible for storing person data then example is available here: [fiddle - use additonal row variable to store person data](http://jsfiddle.net/alepkowski/oxxqdv8s/1/)

```
<form id="fmsubmit" role="form" ng-init="row={}">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in showCase.person" ng-init="row[key]=value">
            <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{key}}" ng-disabled="key=='rowId'" placeholder="{{key}}" name="{{key}}" ng-model="row[key]" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="showCase.submitData(row)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
$scope.showCase = {};
$scope.showCase.person = {
    "id": 2,
        "project": "wewe2012",
        "date": "2013-02-26",
        "description": "ewew",
        "eet_no": "ewew",
};
$scope.showCase.submitData = function (person) {
    console.log(person);
    alert(JSON.stringify(person));
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the row is undefined here. And also it's not applied with the scope. You have to use $scope.$apply() for this. And also why you are using Dynamic ng-models ? with angular static methods and models, you can manage any kind of form. And also try some directives. http://projectslanka.blogspot.com/search/label/AngularJS